# How should I pass sensitive environment variables to Amazon ECS tasks?

Tags: security, docker, passwords, environment-variables, amazon-ecs

What is the recommended way to pass sensitive environment variables, e.g. passwords, to [Amazon ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ecs/) tasks? With Docker Compose, I can use [key-only environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment), which results in the values being read from the OS environment. I can't see any corresponding method for [ECS task definitions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the task definition link you posted there is an "environment" section that allows you to do this. They become environment variables inside the container.

If you mean you would like to keep information outside of the task definition and that task could reference it, you cannot. Your best bet in that case is to have your container pull that information from an outside source and not have the ECS task config try to reference it.

Edit: Im getting downvoted at this point because the parameter store is now the right way to do it. At the time this answer was the most correct way, but the other solutions using SSM are the right way now.

Answer (score 15):

**Approach 1:**

You can use [Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/systems-manager/parameter-store/) to store the variables. If you store them as `SecureString`, the values will be encrypted.

You can reference them as environment variables in the task definition.

You need to retrieve them in the container startup script

```
value_from_parameter_store =`aws ssm get-parameter --name $parameter_store_key --with-decryption --output text --query Parameter.Value --region $REGION `
```

You can also mention `parameter_store_key` as an environment variable. so that you can use `$parameter_store_key`

**Example**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
//some other steps
CMD ["sh","/startup.sh"]
```

startup script:

```
#! /bin/bash
export db_password =`aws ssm get-parameter --name $parameter_store_key --with-decryption --output text --query Parameter.Value --region $REGION `
// Please note that above line has `(backtick) 
// Do other stuff and use this password
```

Put parameter in SSM:

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name 'db_password' --type "SecureString" --value 'P@ssW%rd#1'
```

Docker run command:

```
docker run -e parameter_store_key=db_password -e REGION=us-east-1 <docker_image>
```

**Approach 2:**

Recently AWS announced secrets support in ContainerDefinition for ECS
[Using Secrets in ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html)

Comment: Your concept sounds very good. But I have trouble following it. Can you elaborate a little bit more about the startup script?

Comment: @caliph, Please have a look at this documentation for more details on how docker container startup script works.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Answer (score 8):

Parameter store is the way to go, it stores the variables encrypted using a KMS key.

Amazon has just [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-launches-secrets-support-for-amazon-elastic-container-servic/) support for specifying secrets in the task definition. Reference the parameter value from the SSM and the environment variable to set with the task.

```
{
        ....
        "secrets": [
            {
                "name": "environment_variable_name",
                "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:region:aws_account_id:parameter/parameter_name"
            }
        ]
    }
```

See the official docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html).

There's also a project called [chamber](https://github.com/segmentio/chamber) that can load all parameters from a given path in SSM and set them as environment variables.

Comment: The only drawback is that SSM does not support cross-account parameters. So in a "shared" environment where multiple devs have admin account - they can see all the parameters as well.

Answer (score 4):

if you use environment variables they can be seen when you log into the AWS console.
AWS have written a guide on using proper "secrets" to keep your sensitive data hidden.
The containers load these on startup into memory based environment variables.
Here's a guide: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-manage-secrets-for-amazon-ec2-container-service-based-applications-by-using-amazon-s3-and-docker/

Answer (score 3):

Implementation of pulling environment variables from S3 that [Marc Young](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35662583/80404) mentioned:

https://www.promptworks.com/blog/handling-environment-secrets-in-docker-on-the-aws-container-service

Answer (score 0):

If AWS baked in secrets environments is not an option,
you could also use docker entrypoint to inject secrets at container runtime like in https://medium.com/@zdk/simple-and-secure-way-to-pass-secrets-and-credentials-into-docker-containers-c2f66175b0a4